# md-datepicker shows error when date entered manually

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am using md-datepicker, when i put date manually it is showing invalid date but if i select date from this control then it is validated. for this i have used following code

```
    <md-datepicker name="FromDate" ng-model="vm.user.FromDate" ng-required="true" id="FromDate" md-is-error="login.ToDate.$invalid && login..$submitted" md-placeholder="FromDate"></md-datepicker> 
<div ng-messages="login.FromDate.$error" md-auto-hide="false" ng-show="login.FromDate.$touched ||login.FromDate.$submitted">
<div ng-message="required">Please enter FromDate.</div>                    </div>
```

Comment: Please add more codes or a fiddle/plnkr to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the answer. in config section along with formatDate i added parseDate function and it is working fine no error while manual entry as well as selection from control

```
  .config(function ($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
        $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
            return date ? moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY') : '';
        };

        $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function (dateString) {
            var m = moment(dateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY', true);
            return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the format of the date that you are entering the default format is mm/dd/yyyy