# How to insert date manually without selecting from calendar in md-datepicker in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to insert date manually along with from the datepicker. Where did i need to make the changes.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block margin-bottom-0 edit-actual-date">
     <label>Actual Endd Date</label>
     <md-datepicker md-date-locale="vm.customDateFormat" ng-model="vm.activitySubmandateData.actual_end_date" name="actual_end_date" ng-change="vm.assignAPEDateS()" required></md-datepicker>
        <div ng-messages="roadmap_activity.actual_end_date.$error">
            <small ng-message="required" class="required-field">This field is required.</small>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="vm.activitySubmandateData.actual_start_date && vm.activitySubmandateData.actual_end_date && vm.activitySubmandateData.actual_start_date > vm.activitySubmandateData.actual_end_date">
            <small class="required-field">Actual Start Date can not be before Actual End Date</small>
        </div>
</md-input-container>
```

NB: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432802/md-datepicker-shows-error-when-date-entered-manually) didn't work for me.